# Tmux pane closes unintentionally after script finishes

Tags: tmux

I have a long-running script (a few days) that I run on two environments (staging + prod). Each of these executions will produce about 3MB output in logs that it will print to the screen over time.

I'm running these in tmux, splitting my pane so that one half of the screen is staging and the other half is prod. I then ran the script, checked in every morning and then suddenly one only one split was left. I checked the logs that I tee'ed to a file and the script that was running in the pane that disappeared indeed finished.

I first thought that I accidentially closed it the other evening, but I then repeated that process twice and the exact same thing happened every time. I'm now asking for help to root-cause this :)

Thoughts I had so far:

- Is tmux closing panes if the process that is running in it takes very long (days) ?
- Does the log contain any escape characters that could close the pane?
- Is the pane crashing because too many logs get printed at one point in time?

Note that this script is doing no "active" tmux interaction or anything like that, so it is not calling any tmux commands.

Answer (score 0):

Was the script the only thing running in the pane or did you run it from a shell? If the former, or if you run it from the shell with "exec", then the pane will close when the script finishes.

Other possibilities are something killed the parent shell, or the shell has TMOUT or similar set. Or of course you closed it accidentally or another script did (perhaps by mixing up pane IDs or something).

Try setting the remain-on-exit option in the window and tmux will not close the panes when the program running in them exits and it will tell you if the program exited normally or on a signal.

Comment: Thanks for the TMOUT flag, I will look into that. There is no script running that does any tmux interaction, so can't mixup pane ids or so. I'm running it from bash, `./run.sh | tee logs.txt`